# How to sort drop down list numerically in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatables

I have this code. What it does is simply displaying with DataTables
and put the drop down selection filter for every column at the bottom.

```js
var dataSet = [
  [1,"Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  [2,"Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  [10,"Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  [3,"Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  [5,"Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  [9,"Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  [12,"Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  [23,"Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  [99,"Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];

 $(document).ready(function() {

var columns = [
    {title: "ID"},
    {title: "Name"}, 
    {title: "Position"}, 
    {title: "Office"}, 
    {title: "Extn."}, 
    {title: "Start date"}, 
    {title: "Salary"}
];

// Footer construction
var $tfoot = $("#example tfoot tr");
for (var i = 0, len = columns.length; i < len ; i++){
    $tfoot.append("<th>");
}

$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columns,
    initComplete: function (setting, json) {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
 
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
 
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    } 
    
} );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
<tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

As you can see after running the snippet, the first ID column is not sorted numerically. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

How can enable that?
This is different with other question because it's specific to DataTables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of integers correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Comment: @Hacketo, this is not a duplicate question because array may contain numbers or strings which may not known initially.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com then the first answer does not work with strings values `"111" < "12"` BTW OP state for number. So yes it's a duplicate

Comment: @Gyrocode.com this case is not specific to anything, only sorting an array of data. OP might have remove all not necessary code but he is not able to say what this code is doing. I'm working on this code since yesterday and at the start the code was taken from an example to datatable. OP do not understand a piece of JS

Comment: @Hacketo, [example on DataTables site](http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) is not correct because of the problem the OP found with column containing numerical data. Example on DataTables site works only because the numbers all double-digit which is deceptive.

Comment: @Hacketo, the problem is shown in the question were numbers are sorted as strings without an argument to `sort`. However other columns may need to be sorted as strings or using custom sorting functions if necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

Column data type is automatically determined by jQuery DataTables during initialization, see [data types](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) supported by default.

In `initComplete` function you can temporarily sort each column in ascending order and then restore the initial order once all drop-down boxes are added, see the code below.

```
initComplete: function (settings, json) {
    // Get initial order
    var orderInit = this.api().order();
    
    this.api().columns().every( function (index) {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
            .on( 'change', function () {
                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                    $(this).val()
                );

                column
                    .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                    .draw();
            } );

        // NOTE: Temporarily sort the column data before retrieving it
        // with data() function.
        column.order('asc').draw(false).data().unique().each( function ( d, j ) {
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        } );
    } );
  
    // Restore initial order
    this.api().order(orderInit).draw(false);
}
```

#### DEMO

```js
var dataSet = [
  [1,"Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  [2,"Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  [10,"Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  [3,"Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  [5,"Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  [9,"Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  [12,"Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  [23,"Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  [99,"Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];

$(document).ready(function() {

var columns = [
    {title: "ID"},
    {title: "Name"}, 
    {title: "Position"}, 
    {title: "Office"}, 
    {title: "Extn."}, 
    {title: "Start date"}, 
    {title: "Salary"}
];

// Footer construction
var $tfoot = $("#example tfoot tr");
for (var i = 0, len = columns.length; i < len ; i++){
    $tfoot.append("<th>");
}

$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columns,
    initComplete: function (settings, json) {
        // Get initial order
        var orderInit = this.api().order();
        
        this.api().columns().every( function (index) {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
 
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
 
            column.order('asc').draw(false).data().unique().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
      
        // Restore initial order
        this.api().order(orderInit).draw(false);
    } 
    
} );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
<tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

#### NOTES

See [issue #661 on GitHub](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/661) for more details and further discussion.

Comment: Great answer, but please specify in the solution section about the additional logic for the **Salary** column.

Comment: @neversaint, added much better solution that uses DataTables internal sorting functions and doesn't require custom functions.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com: You're a life saver. Thanks also for answering my 'moving buttons' question.

Comment: Almost 2020 and it's still the correct fix. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

**CAUSE**

By default, array sorting method without the function that defines the sorting order, will sort your array as a string so result that you have is expected. You can read here for more info - [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). So you need to add a function that will sort your data properly for both numbers and strings.

**SOLUTION**

Add `sortFunction` function and use it as an argument for `sort()` function as shown below:

```
var sortFunction = function(a, b) {
    if(a < b) return -1;
    if(a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
};

column.data().unique().sort(sortFunction).each( function ( d, j ) {
```

**DEMO**

```js
var dataSet = [
  [1,"Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  [2,"Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  [10,"Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  [3,"Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  [5,"Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  [9,"Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  [12,"Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  [23,"Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  [99,"Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];

 $(document).ready(function() {

var columns = [
    {title: "ID"},
    {title: "Name"}, 
    {title: "Position"}, 
    {title: "Office"}, 
    {title: "Extn."}, 
    {title: "Start date"}, 
    {title: "Salary"}
];

// Footer construction
var $tfoot = $("#example tfoot tr");
for (var i = 0, len = columns.length; i < len ; i++){
    $tfoot.append("<th>");
}

$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columns,
    initComplete: function (setting, json) {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
 
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
 
                var sortFunction = function(a, b) {
                    if(a < b) return -1;
                    if(a > b) return 1;
                    return 0;
                };
                column.data().unique().sort(sortFunction).each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    } 
    
} );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
<tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Great answer, but If you remove `sort()`, other select boxes will have unsorted data. It's not a complete solution.

Comment: only need to do `return a - b` your code does not handle string values `"111" < "12"` return true

Comment: @Hacketo - are you sure? `return a - b ` will work good only for numbers but we are comparing both numbers and strings. So we need to refactor the whole code - first verify if values in the column is numbers or strings and then use appropriate sorting function.

Comment: The **Salary** column looks like a column with a numbers but in real it is treated as a `string`, because it values have '$' and ',' symbols. So, additional function should be written for this column. For example, the function can clone existing array, modify array of values to array of objects, where each object will have two properties - primary value and modified value - the real number without '$' and ','. Then sort by real numbers, remove them and return correct sorted array of primary values.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary to have the sort() method.

So, just change it :

```
column.data().unique().each( function ( d, j ) {
    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
});
```

Please find the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zlen/ppj1zs7y/1/)

**Edit** : add unique() (I had remove in error) + update jsfiddle

Comment: Thank you @Gyrocode.com ! I,had remove with error. Will change fiddle asap i will be on computer

Comment: Great answer, but If you remove `sort()`, other select boxes will have unsorted data. It's not a complete solution.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com: Thanks. You're right other column need to be properly sorted. For example 2nd or 3rd column may also contain numeric values. How would you approach that?